# Xubuntu 14.04 - PulseAudio / ALSA will not work with USB headset

Tags: usb, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

Being relatively new to Linux, I just shot for Xubuntu. I had to reformat yesterday, because I somehow nuked it in my tired adventures. Ever since then, I haven't been able to get my USB audio working.

When running`lsusb`, my headset shows up as `Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller`  , yet it does not appear when I run`aplay -l` or`aplay -L` [(Results for either command)](http://pastebin.com/YRFQVAn3)

On runnin`pacmd list-sinks`, I only get a [Dummy Output](http://pastebin.com/60WqQrTE)

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how I can sort this out?

Comment: see if this help: http://techscrapbox.blogspot.com.tr/2014/06/enabling-usb-audio-card-in-raspberry-pi.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved!

I spent a fair few hours tinkering before I figured out that I'm an idiot, so I'll write down what I believe I did:

`$ gksudo gedit/yourtexteditor /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Then, at the bottom of the text file, comment out the line that says

> options snd-usb-audio index=-2

Save the file, and then run

`$ gksudo gedit/yourtexteditor /etc/pulse/default.pa`

Add this to the bottom.

> load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:3,0

This is assuming that your device is hw:3,0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:3,0` you can do

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

works fine