# Xubuntu 14.04 USB sound card problems

Tags: 14.04, usb, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I'm having problems getting a USB sound device from Schiit Audio to work.  Goggle found plenty of cases where other people have had problems, but I am past their problems into one of my own.

To start with, let me say what DOES work:
- /proc/asound/cards lists the device
- alsamixer lists it as a valid device
- aplay -l and aplay -L list the device
- the device itself works fine on Windows and a Chromebook (in developer mode). alsamixer on the Chromebook shows the device with a volume slider.

HOWEVER, I cannot switch to the device using alsamixer, and alsamixer shows no volume control on its screen (I can mute and unmute it). [screengrab](http://www.pinewood-wireless.net/efr/imgs/alsamixer.png)

Now, even when I select it, sound continues to play from the previously selected device (speakers, in this case).  My goal is straightforward: switch to the device and back manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: `alsamixer` changes a device's mixer controls; it does not affect what device other programs choose to use. Can't you switch devices in the sound configuration? Did you try `pavucontrol`?

Comment: D'oh!  I thought I had done that, but apparently I hadn't.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Thanks to CL, above.   The key to what I was doing was the persistent change:

```
   $ sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Then, at the bottom of the text file, comment out the line that says

```
    options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

Then, after a reboot (or a force-reload of alsa, probably), pavucontrol lists the device normally.

The above edit is one I learned/stole from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515089/xubuntu-14-04-pulseaudio-alsa-will-not-work-with-usb-headset).